# Why do I get a forbidden response from the graph api when trying to create subscriptions on users' calendars?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

My app uses delegated user access tokens to interact with the MSFT graph api. They have the `Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared` permission. When making requests to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions in production with the following request body:

```
{
     "changeType": "created,updated,deleted",
     "notificationUrl": <https_app_notification_url>,
     "resource": "/me/calendars/<calendar_id>/events",
     "expirationDateTime": (datetime.now(timezone.utc) + timedelta(minutes=4200)).isoformat(),
     "clientState": <a_crypto_random_string>
}
```

almost every time the response is an error with the following in the response body:

```
[Status Code: Forbidden; Reason: Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.]
```

The most recent occurrence of this error had the following `innerError` in the response:

```
{'date': '2020-05-13T20:58:09', 'request-id': '1448e490-9e45-4a08-9aab-dd9c996c18db'}
```

This happens even when trying to subscribe to the user's own default calendar.

The strange thing is that the exact same code, when run on my local machine and tunneled to the web via ngrok to expose my app's notificationUrl endpoint, is able to consistently get a 201 from the MSFT's subscriptions endpoint.

I've checked the system time on the server with the `date` command and there's less than 1 second difference between my local machine and the server. So I don't think the `expirationDateTime` field is the issue; it's got 30 minutes of buffer built in as I believe the max according to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/subscription?view=graph-rest-1.0#maximum-length-of-subscription-per-resource-type) is 4230.

Should I be requesting additional permissions in the oauth scopes for the user access tokens? [The docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions) say that `Calendars.Read` is enough so I would've thought `Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared` would do it. Or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 0):

You need `Calendars.Read` as outlined in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to subscribe to the current user's calendar.

Comment: Right, my app has the delegated permission `Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared` which according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#calendars-permissions) is a superset of `Calendars.Read`, I shouldn't need to request `Calendars.Read` explicitly. In any case, I tried explicitly requesting `Calendars.Read` in addition to `Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared` and the problem persists. The most recent `request-id` from the `innerError` on the response is `70404269-c0b9-48c6-b7b5-8138ab7c260a`. Is it possible to get more detailed information from that?

Comment: If it's not working with Calendars.Read, you should contact support to investigate the issue https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/support